# Error: Module '"typescript-declarations"' has no exported member 'ICoordinates'

Tags: typescript, types, typescript-typings

**Overview:**
I'm building a TypeScript declarations NPM/GitHub Packages library (https://github.com/jefelewis/typescript-declarations) that I want to import into my projects, but I'm having an issue with importing into projects.

**Project:**

```js
import { ICoordinates } from 'typescript-declarations';
```

**Error:**

```js
Module '"typescript-declarations"' has no exported member 'ICoordinates'.
```

**What I've tried:**

- I've tried modifying the `package.json`
- I've tried modifying the `tsonfig.json`
- I've exported the `type` and `interface` from `src/types/locationTypes.ts`

**Possible Options:**

- Do I need to use a reference in `index.ts` such as https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/namespaces-and-modules.html#-reference-ing-a-module

**src/index.ts**

```js
// Imports: TypeScript Types
import * as locationTypes from './types/locationTypes';
import * as measurementTypes from './types/measurementTypes';

// Exports
export {
  locationTypes,
  measurementTypes,
};
```

**src/types/locationTypes.ts:**

```js
// Module: Location Types
declare module locationTypes {
  // TypeScript Type: Latitude
  export type TLatitude = number;

  // TypeScript Type: TLongitude
  export type TLongitude = number;

  // TypeScript Type: Coordinates
  export interface ICoordinates {
    latitude: TLatitude;
    longitude: TLongitude;
  }
}

// Exports
export default locationTypes;
```

**src/types/measurementTypes.ts:**

```js
// Module: Measurement Types
declare module measurementTypes {
    // TypeScript Type: Measurement (Distance)
    export type TMeasurementDistance = 'Kilometers' | 'Miles' | 'Yards' | 'Feet';

    // TypeScript Type: Measurement (Length)
    export type TMeasurementLength = 'Inches' | 'Feet' | 'Yards' | 'Miles' | 'Light Years' | 'Millimeters' | 'Centimeters' | 'Meters' | 'Kilometers';

    // TypeScript Type: Measurement (Speed)
    export type TMeasurementSpeed = 'Centimeters Per Second' | 'Meters Per Second' | 'Feet Per Second' | 'Miles Per Hour' | 'Kilometers Per Hour' | 'Knots' | 'Mach';

    // TypeScript Type: Measurement (Angle)
    export type TMeasurementAngle = 'Degrees' | 'Radians' | 'Milliradians';
}

// Exports
export default measurementTypes;
```

Answer (score 1):

There are some issues with your type definitions aswell as package build pipeline.

- you don't have to [`cd`](https://github.com/jefelewis/typescript-declarations/blob/07525c1/package.json#L16) into `src` directory to run `tsc`. It's already described in your [`tsconfig`](https://github.com/jefelewis/typescript-declarations/blob/07525c17767afbe1074f9f7c6561c7e639d8f86c/tsconfig.json#L2) which files should be included in compilation.
- your [`cp`](https://github.com/jefelewis/typescript-declarations/blob/07525c17767afbe1074f9f7c6561c7e639d8f86c/package.json#L16) command is malformed. `cp` requires the second argument. To know the target file/directory to copy the source file to. Though I believe you don't need to copy `package.json` anywhere. The one in the root is describing your `npm` package just fine. Though it definitely maybe not true if you have some elaborated package publishing scripts I'm not aware of.
- there are unnecessary internal modules (`declare module someModule`) inside your type definitions. That's a really old legacy feature of typescript replaced now with [`namespaces`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/namespaces.html). Accounting for how you're trying to import `ICoordinates` I'm assuming you don't need namspaces either.
- [exporting](https://github.com/jefelewis/typescript-declarations/blob/07525c17767afbe1074f9f7c6561c7e639d8f86c/src/index.ts#L6-L9) `locationTypes` as `export { locationTypes }` you're creating yet another namespace `locationTypes` your types from `locationTypes.ts` are now under.

All in all you still can import `ICoordinates` as:

```ts
import { locationTypes } from 'typescript-declarations'

const coords: locationTypes.default.ICoordinates = null as any
```

Though if you expect to import the same type as:

```ts
import { ICoordinates } from 'typescript-declarations'
```

you'll have to make some adjustments to your code:

```ts
// --- src/types/locationsTypes.ts
// TypeScript Type: Latitude
export type TLatitude = number;

// TypeScript Type: TLongitude
export type TLongitude = number;

// TypeScript Type: Coordinates
export interface ICoordinates {
  latitude: TLatitude;
  longitude: TLongitude;
}

// --- src/index.ts
// re-export all members of `locationTypes`
export * from './types/locationsTypes'
```

The same goes for `measurementTypes` if you want to import them without explicit namespace.